# Should I use a HTTP server or a FTP server for file download ? How can I use a P2P protocol here?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, ftp, p2p

In my webapp users can download the files among themselves. If a user `A` has shared a file `F` , then user `B` after connecting to `A` can download the file `F` from `A`. Till now each user makes a simple `HTTP` connection like :`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/FileList` with another user. The file resides on the local hard disk of each user. So that a user can download a file there were two options in my mind.

- As the user shares a file,copy that file into the web-app directory of the server,so that the download link becomes as simple as `<a href="./FileToDownload">Click to download</a>`.
- Run a separate FTP server on each node.

I don't know which one of these is a better option but the first one seems very simple to me. What are the ways each client can share the files,without having to copy the stuff somewhere in the `webapp` directory. ***How in this case I can use a P2P protocol ?***

*NOTE : I am using Tomcat 7.*

Comment: you cannot share a file from a client to another client only by using the http protocol or only tomcat server. You need a P2P connection between the  2 clients. If you don't want store the file on the server, that also means that when user A is offline the files he shares are also unavailable for other users.

Comment: I don't know what the purpose is and if all files shared are always shared for every other user. Or if a users can point out what files he wants to share with user B and what other files he wants to share with user C. If all available for everyone. Why don't you setup a simple ftp server. All files uploaded to the server can then be downloaded by everybody.

Comment: @roel I don't want to upload the files to a server.Users will download the file from other users by connecting to their nodes.

Comment: Have you thought about NAT and Firewalls? Should not be too easy to always get stable connections between any 2 nodes. Not without using some kind of relay or proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Real P2P is impossible without opening a listening socket on the client machine (that imposes you have to install something on client machine).

If you don't want to STORE the files on the server, I would rather recommend a "connection server", which serves as a gateway between the two users. User A will upload, user B will download at the same time, all you need is to make the bytebuffer in memory. The downloaded bytes can be dropped.

You can write a small client-side program in any language for updating the available files, and receiving the upload request from the server side (also execute the upload)
I would recommend using TCP sockets for upload to the server side, this way you have direct control over the uploaded bytes (streams).

There are some interesting technical issues here (blocking streams, metadata (filename, length, createdate, ...), data consistency, error handling, etc.) that should be taken into consideration. Nice task.

I don't recommend FTP because you cannot control the authentication and authorisation (who can see the files).